# How to update boolean in hql?

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean, hql

Here's my code:

```java
public static boolean alterReservation(int reservationId) {
    try {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session
                        .createQuery("update Reservation  set realized = true where id= :reservationId");
        query.setParameter("reservationId", reservationId);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
update Reservation  set realized = true where id= :reservationId
```

Doesn't work I get no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have not execute the query you should do:

```
.....
  Query query = session.createQuery("update Reservation  set realized = true where id= :reservationId");
  query.setParameter("reservationId", reservationId);
  query.executeUpdate();  <<<<<<<<<<
.....
```

Comment: @czesiek, NP we all fall for that sometimes, feel free to mark answer as accepted if it solves your problem